# What Linux class is equivalent to CStdioFile

Tags: linux, windows, file, porting

Which Linux class is equivalent to Windows MFC class CStdioFile?

I am porting some class to linux.

Comment: In the Windows world the "desktop" is integrated into the OS. In the Linux world this is not the case, there are multiple desktop/GUI's: KDE, Gnome, Xfce, etc. - and many Linux machines have no GUI at all. So the phrase "I'm porting some class to Linux" doesn't make much sense. For creating cross-platform software I definitely agree with Didier's suggestion for using wxWidgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such Linux class equivalent. MFC does not exist on Linux. (I thought it had disappeared on Windows btw.)

Your best bet to have as close as possible equivalent of MFC classes on Linux is to use wxWidgets. It has a for example a `wxFFile` class for buffered I/O.

Otherwise, use the C++ class `std::iostream`. The interface is really different from `CFile` though.